# The behavior of an $H^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ function close to $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, asymptotics, hilbert-spaces, approximation-theory

This question is related to [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513821/the-behavior-of-an-l2-mathbbr-function-close-to-x-0). The question below is my original one but I thought that the answer to [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513821/the-behavior-of-an-l2-mathbbr-function-close-to-x-0) was a simple way to solve my issue. @David C. Ullrich proved me wrong. So, let me ask the question I wanted to ask originally:

Is there a way to prove that an $H^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ function $f$, with $f(0)=0$, close to $x=0$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2})$? In other words, can we prove that there is a function $\tilde{f}$ equal to $f$ almost everywhere such that
$$
\limsup_{x\to 0} \left(|x|^{-1/2} |\tilde{f}|\right)<\infty?
$$
I am working on a proof involving $H^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$, and this fact would be really useful. It seems reasonable since the derivative needs to be integrable across $x=0$, and $f(0)=0$, but, like the other question, I am not exactly sure how to prove that. No need of the detailed proof, just an idea of what tool I should be using.

One would think that is is possible to integrate from 0 to $x$ @David C. Ullrich's counterexample given to [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4513821/the-behavior-of-an-l2-mathbbr-function-close-to-x-0) to produce a counterexample here. However, it does not seem that trivial to do, given the definition of his function.

Comment: By sobolev embedding theorem, if $s = n/2 + a$ with $0 < a < 1$, then $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is continuously included into $C^{a}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now take $n = 1$, $s = 1$ to see that $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ is continuously included into $C^{1/2}(\mathbb{R})$. Use the extension operator $E : H^1(\mathbb{R}^+) \to H^1(\mathbb{R})$ to get that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is continuously included in $C^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question in a very simple and direct way!

Comment: @Mason Actually, is there a way to push this a little further and say $f$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^s)$ for some $s>1/2$, since $f'$ must be squared integrable through the origin?

Comment: I'm going to guess no, but I haven't made any attempt at actually trying this on some singular $H^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ functions. My guess is that since the Sobolev embedding is sharp (?), the examples that show that this embedding is sharp may show that $s > 1/2$ is not possible

Comment: @Mason If I can pick your brain some more. After writing this comment, I realized that what I really need is $v/x$ to be in $L^2$. Which is "almost" the case since $v$ is $\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2})$, but not quite. Again, it seems like since $v'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, it should be the case. However, I don't have a formal proof. I am happy to make that a formal question if you want. Any intuitive idea you would have would be appreciated and thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Mason Also, if you want to write your first comment as an "answer" below, I will be happy to approve it so you get "credit".

Comment: My idea is to let $v$ be one of the cases, if it exists, where the inclusion $H^1 \to C^{1/2}$ is sharp, meaning $v \notin C^a$ for $a > 1/2$. I suspect it might not satisfy your assertion.